# REGEX for password validation

Tags: .net, regex

- min 3 letters
- max 15
- characters A-Za-z0-9
- special charaters @#$%^&+=

This is what I have:

```
Regex.IsMatch(Password.Text, @"^[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{3,15}$ ")
```

It always returns false.

Please help.

Comment: Offtopic, but what if I would like to use `<>` in my password for more security? or more than 15 characters? (I actually have a password that is longer than that used in ultrasecure cases)

Comment: @aloo - you've got an underscore between the A and the Z - so you're not matching on B-Y; also 215 - should that be 15?  Or are those posting typos?

Comment: @moonshadow, why not make an answer instead of comment?

Comment: How many of normal chars? How many of special chars? You didn't cover that in both your requirements and the regex. This would make `abc` valid.

Comment: sorry, its a typo
Regex.IsMatch(Password.Text, @"^[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{3,15}$ ")

Comment: No love for the password generators that use base64, which use the additional symbol `/`

Comment: Using this mask, aaa will be accepted as a password right? Just checking what kind of rules you want to enforce. From a security point of view I would expect at least one lower case, one upper case and one special character. And as other people already commented on the 3 to 15 characters restriction, this seems to weak...

Comment: @earlz: I wasn't expecting that to be the sum total of the problems :)

Answer (score 3):

Take out the space at the end of the regular expression string.  Also: corrected probable typos.

```
Regex.IsMatch(Password.Text, @"^[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{3,15}$")
```

Comment: didn't he also mean for it to be `^[A-Z...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth do you want to *restrict* possible passwords?!?

- Why forbid french and german characters (unicode in general)?
- Why limit passwords to 15 chars? A lot of people use whole passphrases.
- Why limit the special characters? Why do you rule out `.` and `:`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is a **very very** bad idea. The much better approach would be to test the **password strength** of the entered password and set a score passwords have to beat.

There are algorithms to compute the strength of passwords. The following is taken from the Delphi Encryption Compendium by Hagen Reddmann (an thus in Pascal, but i guess this can be translated easily)

```
function PassphraseQuality(const Password: String): Extended; 
// returns computed Quality in range 0.0 to 1.0 
// source extracted from Delphi Encryption Compendium, DEC 

  function Entropy(P: PByteArray; L: Integer): Extended; 
  var 
    Freq: Extended; 
    I: Integer; 
    Accu: array[Byte] of LongWord; 
  begin 
    Result := 0.0; 
    if L <= 0 then Exit; 
    FillChar(Accu, SizeOf(Accu), 0); 
    for I := 0 to L-1 do Inc(Accu[P[I]]); 
    for I := 0 to 255 do 
      if Accu[I] <> 0 then 
      begin 
        Freq := Accu[I] / L; 
        Result := Result - Freq * (Ln(Freq) / Ln(2)); 
      end; 
  end; 

  function Differency: Extended; 
  var 
    S: String; 
    L,I: Integer; 
  begin 
    Result := 0.0; 
    L := Length(Password); 
    if L <= 1 then Exit; 
    SetLength(S, L-1); 
    for I := 2 to L do 
      Byte(S[I-1]) := Byte(Password[I-1]) - Byte(Password[I]); 
    Result := Entropy(Pointer(S), Length(S)); 
  end; 

  function KeyDiff: Extended; 
  const 
    Table = '^1234567890ß´qwertzuiopü+asdfghjklöä#<yxcvbnm,.-°!"§$%&/()=?`QWERTZUIOPÜ*ASDFGHJKLÖÄ''>YXCVBNM;:_'; 
  var 
    S: String; 
    L,I,J: Integer; 
  begin 
    Result := 0.0; 
    L := Length(Password); 
    if L <= 1 then Exit; 
    S := Password; 
    UniqueString(S); 
    for I := 1 to L do 
    begin 
      J := Pos(S[I], Table); 
      if J > 0 then S[I] := Char(J); 
    end; 
    for I := 2 to L do 
      Byte(S[I-1]) := Byte(S[I-1]) - Byte(S[I]); 
    Result := Entropy(Pointer(S), L-1); 
  end; 

const 
  GoodLength = 10.0; // good length of Passphrases 
var 
  L: Extended; 
begin 
  Result := Entropy(Pointer(Password), Length(Password)); 
  if Result <> 0 then 
  begin 
    Result := Result * (Ln(Length(Password)) / Ln(GoodLength)); 
    L := KeyDiff + Differency; 
    if L <> 0 then L := L / 64; 
    Result := Result * L; 
    if Result < 0 then Result := -Result; 
    if Result > 1 then Result := 1; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Indeed.  the 'password' library for Ruby makes it easy to check password strength.  The library calls cracklib, which does many more and better checks than most programmers will want to do.  For example, it will check that the password is not a dictionary word.

Comment: My purpose is to prevent cross browser scripting .If anybody can tell me how i can do that for  a password field.

Comment: @aloo:  If this password is never displayed on a page (which is **should never be** anyways), then cross site scripting is not a problem.  The real problem is SQL injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which you can prevent by writing proper SQL queries (see the wiki page).

Comment: THanks for all your answers.After reading BlueRaja's comment, it makes sense not to add restriction to  password field.